# What is exactly Smalltalk language used for?

Tags: smalltalk

What is exactly Smalltalk used for? Creating websites? Trying to understand what can be built using this language.

Also,what are the tools that are used to code in Smalltalk? I google and see Pharo as one such tool.

Answer (score 10):

> What is exactly small talk used for ?

Everything.

> Creating websites ?

Yes.

> Trying to understand what can be built using this language.

Everything. Smalltalk is Turing-complete and "Tetris-complete". It can be used for anything and everything any other language can be used for.

Things that have been built in Smalltalk:

- Operating Systems
- VMs (including Smalltalk VMs)
- Compilers (including Smalltalk compilers)
- Smalltalk IDEs (in fact, Smalltalk invented the concept of the IDE)
- GUI Frameworks
- Desktop systems (in fact, Smalltalk invented the concept of the desktop with overlapping windows as we know it today)
- Embedded Systems (for example, the famous Tektronix oscilloscopes)
- Office suites
- CPU layout tools
- Websites
- Webservices
- Games
- Virtual Worlds
- Simulations
- AI
- …

> Also,what are the tools that are used to code in small talk ?

Smalltalk Systems are typically all-encompassing systems that provide everything, from the VM, compiler, debugger, IDE, version control, GUI, widgets, frameworks, tools, and libraries in one. In other words, you don't use "tools" to code in Smalltalk, you use Smalltalk to code in Smalltalk.

Comment: Can we use small talk web services to load data into oracle

Comment: What about "It can be used for anything and everything any other language can be used for" is hard to understand? Smalltalk is a programming language. Pretty much every programming language can be used to solve pretty much every problem. Therefore, Smalltalk can be used to solved every problem.